# nose.plugins.cover: ERROR: Coverage not available: unable to import coverage module

Tags: python, nose, coverage.py

When trying to compute coverage for a python project, I run into the following error:

```
nose.plugins.xcover: ERROR: Coverage not available: unable to import coverage module
```

This is the command I'm running:

```
nosetests --verbosity=3 --with-xcoverage --cover-package=mypackage--nocapture --nologcapture --with-xunit --cover-inclusive
```

I don't know why I'm getting the error, I have the `coverage` package installed, nosetests has the two plugins coverage and xcoverage.

This is the output from `pip freeze`:

```
certifi==2018.4.16
chardet==3.0.4
coverage==4.5.1
fasteners==0.14.1
idna==2.7
jenkins-job-builder==2.2.1
jenkinsapi==0.3.6
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.0
monotonic==1.5
multi-key-dict==2.0.3
nose==1.3.7
nosexcover==1.0.11
pbr==4.2.0
psutil==5.4.6
python-jenkins==1.1.0
pytz==2018.5
PyYAML==3.13
requests==2.19.1
six==1.11.0
stevedore==1.29.0
tornado==5.1
urllib3==1.23
websocket-client==0.48.0
```

And the output from `nosetests --plugins`:

```
Plugin capture
Plugin failuredetail
Plugin xunit
Plugin deprecated
Plugin skip
Plugin multiprocess
Plugin logcapture
Plugin xcoverage
Plugin coverage
Plugin attributeselector
Plugin doctest
Plugin profile
Plugin id
Plugin allmodules
Plugin collect-only
Plugin isolation
Plugin pdb
```

I'm using Python 3.7.0 on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your `pip` command is installed into a different Python than `nosetest` is.  Try using `python -m pip` and `python -m nose.main` so that everything is coming from the same installation.